# Flutter sending UTF8 toJava/Kotlin's using DataInputStream and readUTF

Tags: java, flutter, kotlin, dart, sockets

Currently, we are trying to write a Flutter-Dart client (ported from a Java Client) using sockets for transferring plaintext-data and files.

The Server is written in Kotlin and works well with Kotlin clients sending a UTF Package (information about the binary package sent after), followed by a long package defining the package size and finally the binary data.

A small truncated sample code for the server is:

```
class DataProcessRunnable internal constructor(private val socket: Socket, private val onFileReceivedListener: OnFileReceivedListener) : Runnable {
    private val dateFormat = SimpleDateFormat("HH-mm-ss")
    private val dateDayFormat = SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd")
    override fun run() {
    try {
        DataInputStream(socket.getInputStream()).use { stream ->

            print ("connected ${stream.toString()}")
 
            val rawData = stream.readUTF();
            print("Rawdata: $rawData")
            val fileData = gson.fromJson(rawData, FileData::class.java)
            fileData.ipAddress = socket.inetAddress.hostAddress
            val fileSize = stream.readLong()
            println("sender: " + socket.inetAddress)
            println("Filedata:$fileData")
            println("filesize:$fileSize")
            var fileName = "noname"
          
            val fileTransfer = FileTransfer()
            fileTransfer.fileSize = fileSize
            fileTransfer.filename = fileName
            println("filename:$fileName")
            try {
                 try {

                    try {


                        GZIPInputStream(stream).use { input ->
                            FileOutputStream(fileName).use { out ->
                                input.copyTo(out)
                            }
                        }


                    } catch (ex: Exception) {
                        ex.printStackTrace()
                    } finally {
                        println("Wrote File in GZIP")
                    }
                    fileTransfer.transferedSize = fileTransfer.fileSize
                    val fData = FileData()
                    fData.file = File(fileName)
                    fData.extras = fileData.extras
                    fData.ipAddress = socket.inetAddress.toString()
                    fData.type = fileData.type
                    onFileReceivedListener.fileReceived(fData)
                } catch (ex: Exception) {
                    ex.printStackTrace()
                }
            } catch (ex: Exception) {
                ex.printStackTrace()
            }
        }
    } catch (ex: Exception) {
        ex.printStackTrace()
    }
  }
}
```

When we use Flutter-Dart to establish a socket, we are trying to send the first UTF8-Package using that codesample. The connection is established but readUTF can't read any data.

```
await Socket.connect('dev1.local-cloud-server.local', 2555).then((socket) {
          socket.writeln(gzip.encode(utf8.encode(fData.toString())));
          socket.flush();
        });
       });
```

After trying around several methods to send a utf8 encoded string from flutter dart to java, the only way I was able to read the first package was using (on the serverside, code truncated):

```
private fun validateSocketConnection2(socket: Socket) {
    Thread {
                DataInputStream(socket.getInputStream()).use { stream ->
                    val rawData = stream.bufferedReader().forEachLine { println(it) }
                    print("Rawdata: $rawData")
     }.start()

}
```

Using a bufferedreader i was able to read the utf8 encoded string properly, but that would break the whole kotlin server code for other clients. In Flutter-Dart we tried to use sockets.add(), sockets.write("...\n"), sockets.writeln(), await socket.flush() after every package sent and also socket.close() to ensure that all data were transmitted.

But we were not able to read data using readUTF as we do for any other Java/Kotlin/C# client.

What are we missing to get readUTF working?

Comment: You shouldn't be using `DataInputStream`/`DataOutputStream`, it is the wrong tool for the job. The `readUTF` method expects a specific **binary** format where the first four bytes represent a big-endian integer with the length of the following data in bytes, followed by the data in **modified UTF-8** format (which is not normal UTF-8 format). You need to use a `GZipInputStream` and wrap that in a `InputStreamReader` configured with UTF-8.

Comment: Sadly we can't change the server that easy because we are just extending clients using an old piece of history. Is there no way to get dart using proper formatted utf8 strings?

Comment: Read the documentation and implementation of [`DataOutputStream`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/io/DataOutputStream.html) and [`DataOutput`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/io/DataOutput.html) method `writeUTF` (and probably `writeLong`), it describes exactly how it works. Your current Dart code in no way does what the server expects (e.g. the only thing gzipped is the file data **after** the file information and file length)

Comment: Just found the following code, which shows how to use DataStreams (for files), but it's by far more complicated as expected. Sadly, that there is no built-in-method or a proper dart module for that case. 
https://github.com/zathras/misc/blob/master/dart/jovial_misc/lib/io_utils.dart